How can I add Font Awesome icon inside password text input element
I have this code for adding font awesome icon inside of the password textbox. But the Icon not visible inside of the text box and I think the text box is not enough space to accommodate font awesome icon. Can anyone point me in the right direction to get the icon inside the text box? Here is my code
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.PasswordFor(m=>m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" autocomplete ="off" })
    <span>
     <i class= "fa-regular fa-eye"></i>
    </span>
</div>  


for bootstrap you could use input groups: link. But it is next to the textbox not in the textbox.


Icon not visible inside of the text box and I think the text box is
not enough space to accommodate font awesome icon. How can I add Font
Awesome icon inside password text input element

Well according to your scenario, you can't directly place an icon inside the input elemen becuase, additional Icon class characters would overlap or push the icon around, creating a confusing user experience.
Another issue is, The  element has limited built-in formatting capabilities. While you can control some aspects like size and borders, adding elements like icons directly isn't possible.
Instead of doing that, you can effectively make it appear within the text box using CSS positioning techniques.
By using CSS positioning techniques, we achieve the visual effect of having the icon within the input field while maintaining the functionality of the input element itself.
Let's have a look, how we could do that:
HTML:
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="password-wrapper">
        <input type="password" class="form-control password-field" autocomplete="off" />
        <span class="password-toggle">
            <i class="far fa-eye"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

Custom CSS:
<style>
    .password-wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }

    .form-control {
        padding-right: 40px; 
    }

    .password-toggle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 10px; 
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .password-toggle i {
            color: #777;
        }

     .password-toggle i:hover {
                color: #333; 
            }
</style>

Note: Please, adjust this value to accommodate the icon, distance from the input field, color of the icon and the hover effect based on your requirement.
Output:

